# Which is the best way to hide IntVar values in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display IntVar values only after the button is clicked. Is there a way to hide them prior to the first click?

If not, what is a good alternative to do so?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
root = tk.Tk()

dice = []
score = tk.IntVar()

def Roll():
    score.set(0)
    for _ in range(5):
        dice[_].set(random.choice([*range(6)])+1)
        score.set(score.get()+dice[_].get())

for _ in range(5):
    dice.append(tk.IntVar())
    tk.Label(root, textvar = dice[_]).grid(row=_, column=0)

tk.Button(root, text='Roll dice', command=Roll).grid(row=0, column=2)
tk.Label(root, textvar = score).grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `dice.append(tk.IntVar())` to `dice.append(tk.IntVar(value=''))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid_remove() to "hide" a widget.
Here is a sample code (not tested)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
root = tk.Tk()

dice = []
labels = []
score = tk.IntVar()

def Roll():
    score.set(0)
    for _ in range(5):
        dice[_].set(random.choice([*range(6)])+1)
        score.set(score.get()+dice[_].get())
    for l in labels:
        l.grid() # show again the labels

for _ in range(5):
    dice.append(tk.IntVar())
    l = tk.Label(root, textvar = dice[_])
    l.grid(row=_, column=0)
    labels.append(l)

for l in labels:
    l.grid_remove() # hide the labels

tk.Button(root, text='Roll dice', command=Roll).grid(row=0, column=2)
tk.Label(root, textvar = score).grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```